# how to send a message from jsp/servlet/swing?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

thank you t give me answer of my past quetion.

this question is for the swing/jsp/servlet. 
i want a code for send a message by smtp or other using swing / jsp / sevlet..
and how to make a jar file f our swing program in netbeans..

thanks you 
mihir

Comment: can you properly listout all your questions ?

Comment: bro. u can get t massage frm jsp bt not frmo swing. serlvet/swing no massage good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send an email from jsp/servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757442/how-to-send-an-email-from-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a mail message through your java application, you might want to take a look at the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/index.html) which can be obtained from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-139225.html). However, just as org.life.java said, you need to restructure your question to make it clearer.